# Is there a way to hide my Google Analytics snippet so it can't be copied or spammed?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

When I view the page source of my website, I can see my Google Analytics snippet:

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12367889-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-12367889-1');
 gtag('config', 'AW-608708765');
</script>
```

I tried pasting this code into a local file and opening that file in a browser.  Google Analytics counted the hit that wasn't from my website.

That means everyone can copy my code and use for fake traffic.  How can I prevent that?

Comment: GA has had issues in the last few years with fake traffic, especially spam injected into GA reports.   See our tag [Tag:google-analytics-spam] for bunch of questions folks have asked about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set up a 'Custom Filter' to only include data from your domain. This filter should then prevent your data from being corrupted if someone copies and uses your tracking snippet on another domain.

**So, it would be something like this:**

1. Admin
2. Filters
3. Add Filter
4. Pic a name
5. Choose 'Custom'
6. Choose 'Include'
7. Choose 'Hostname' in the dropdown
8. Write your hostname with a \ before the dot, like this `\.com`
9. Click Save

**Here's two blog post describing the solution:**

https://www.wetpaintwebtools.com/blog/how-to-protect-your-google-analytics-data-from-spam/

https://neilpatel.com/blog/protect-analytics-from-hacking/